# Can I store multiple values in array?

Tags: php, arrays

For example I have a `li` and every `li` has an `<a>`
Here's my code for it.

```
include 'functions/class.php';

$db = new DB();
$warriors = array();
$result=$db->getWarriors();

foreach($result as $names) {
    echo '<li><a href="display_warrior.php id='.$names['warrior_id'].'">'.$names['warrior_name'].'</a></li>';
}
```

I want to happen is that for example It displayed 3 values from my database when I click a specific link its id will go directly to an array and when I click another a it adds to the array so there are already 2 values in my array how can I do that?

retrieving values

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $values = array($_GET['id']);//it overwrites how to do the right way?
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for sessions..?

Comment: I want to happen is that for example I click name 1 and has an Id of N0001 and I click name 2 has an Id of N0002 so In my array I have N0001 and N0001 is that possible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Again, you are probably looking for **sessions**. Find a tutorial about those.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for this instead:

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $values['id'] = $_GET['id'];
}
```

**Update**

Is this what you want?

```
<?php
    if (!empty($_GET["values"])) {
        $currentOptionsArray = explode(",", $_GET["values"]);
        $currentOptionsText = implode(",", $currentOptionsArray) . ",";
    } else {
        $currentOptionsText = "";
    }
?>
<a href="?values=<?=$currentOptionsText?>option1">Option 1</a>
<a href="?values=<?=$currentOptionsText?>option2">Option 2</a>
<a href="?values=<?=$currentOptionsText?>option3">Option 3</a>
```

Comment: it still overwrites , I want to happen is that for example I click name 1 and has an Id of N0001 and I click name 2 has an Id of N0002 so In my array I have N0001 and N0001 is that possible?